# Python plotly line chart y-axis prints in order it is read from CSV rather than sequentially

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly

I have a CSV file with dates in column A (MMM-YYYY) and cumulative percentage stock returns in column B, C and D. I am trying to create a line chart to compare the performance of the stocks over the period. However, when I run my code, the y-axis isn't in numerical order (low to high) like it would be in excel e.g. I expect the y-axis to begin with the lowest value and end with the highest. Does anyone know how to correct this?

My code and the output can be seen below.

```
   import plotly.express as px
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

   Return = pd.read_csv('MonthlyReturnsColumn.csv')
   fig = px.line(Return, x="Month", y=Return.columns[1:4], title="Cumulative Return")
   fig.update_yaxes(type ='category')
   fig.show()
```

[image: y-axis jumbled]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem: the CSV data were strings instead of floats. The easiest fix was to change the file format back to *xlsx*. The new code will be as:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Return = pd.read_excel('MonthlyReturnsColumn.xlsx')
fig = px.line(Return, x="Month", y=Return.columns[1:4], title="Cumulative Return")      
fig.show()
```

The resulted plot will be:
[image: Updated plot]